# Sorting an Input List

Tags: perl

I have an input list that is being provided by a system that tracks metrics.  I need to sort it in order to remove usage data that is below a given threshold and I really have no idea how to approach it.  The data that is fed to me should look similar to this:

```
ID                    Usage                  Estimated Cost
------------------------------------------------------------------
University Name       260000                 1600.00
```

The first field will be a name, and the following two fields will be integer values.
I was thinking about trying to create list of lists, but there is probably an easier way.
How would I go about removing just getting the 3 fields and sorting them by the usage value?

Comment: Do you need it sorted, or can you just use Perl's `grep` to build a list that only has usages at or above the threshold?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A list of lists is pretty easy.

```
my @list;
while(<>) {
    push @list, [$_,(split(/\s+/,$_,3))[1]];
}
foreach my $out (sort {$a->[1] <=> $b->[1]} @list) {
    print $out->[0];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can remember the whole line so you do not have to format it again. Also, only remember and sort the lines whose usage value is over the threshold:

```
perl -ane 'BEGIN { $threshold = 2000 }              # Insert your value here.
           next if 1 .. 2 or $F[-2] < $threshold;   # Skip the header and filtered lines.
           push @A, [ $F[-2], $_ ];                 # Remember the usage and the whole line.
           }{                                       # At the end...
           print map $_->[1],
                 sort { $a->[0] <=> $b->[0] } @A'
```

Answer (score 1):

The standard approach is to create a list of hashes. In your case you would convert your input file into something:

```
my @records = (
  { ID => "University Name", Usage => 260000, EstCost => 1600.00 },
  { ID => "...", Usage => 12345, EstCost => 9999.99 },
  ...

);
```

Then sort them (e.g. by Usage) with code like:

```
my @sorted = sort { $a->{Usage} <=> $b->{Usage} } @records;
```

Then create a report from the sorted records with code like:

```
for my $r (@sorted) {
  print "ID: ", $r->{ID}, ..., "\n";
}
```

You can take short cuts if you want, but transforming each line into a hash has several advantages:

- it makes your code easier to read, understand and modify - i.e. it is obvious that `sort { $a->{Usage} <=> $b->{Usage} ...` sorts by Usage
- there are so many other libraries which operate on list of hashes, i.e. there are libraries which convert list of hashes to a CSV file or an HTML table or a plain text table or insert the rows into a database, etc.